# Exclude PIDs when comparing strace output

Tags: diff, strace

I want to debug like:

```
strace -fe open python /usr/bin/gnome-tweak-tool 2>>/tmp/hello.log

strace -fe open python /usr/bin/gnome-tweak-tool 2>>/tmp/hello2.log
```

Then use kdiff3 to compare both logs, but different pids will make this comparison useless:
[image]

So my question is there any option from strace to exclude such -f pid ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could log the outputs of the different pids to different files via the `-ff -o filename` options:

```
strace -o foo -ff -e open  perl -e fork
strace -o bar -ff -e open  perl -e fork
```

and then compare the appropriate `foo.<pidnum>` and `bar.<pidnum>` files.

Comment: A side note, `cat bar* > mybar && cat foo* > myfoo && kdiff3 mybar myfoo` to compare in one step.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r -e 's/^(.+)pid [0-9]+(.+)$/\1pid-xxxx\2/;' -i /tmp/hello2.log
```

or filter it same way from output.

Comment: I don't get what should be replace for this `pid-xxxx`. Empty output when i run  `sed -r -e 's/pid-[0-9]+/pid-12625/;' -i hello3.log` which 12625 is one of the pid in this file. And there are a lot of pids and i need to figure out the unqiue pids one by one?

Comment: @林果皞 ohh, sorry, my bad, test file not like yours. Changed, should work this time.

Comment: *pid-xxxx* is just any token, you may set it to empty, just something equal for both files - it will make diff happy

Comment: The hello3.log doesn't change(should i expect `[pid 12606] +++ exited with 0 +++` will shrink to `+++ exited with 0 +++` ?) and empty output in terminal when i run `sed -r -e 's/^(.+)pid-[0-9]+(.+)$/\1pid-12606\2/;' -i ./hello3.log`, my sed version is  `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Comment: @林果皞 yes definitely, because *pid 12606*  is't same as *pid-12606*, sorry again, checked on strace output this time, edited, should work this time. huh.